# Is there a recommended practice for implementing a Password Vault / Credential Cache to achieve Single Sign-On?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, office365, claims-based-identity, azure-active-directory

We're building an ASP.Net MVC portal system that use Office 365 / Azure AD for authentication. In addition to displaying info from Office 365 such as the current user's latest emails and calendar items, the portal will also include a number of "windows" into other key applications relevant to the current user. By "window" this would typically mean calling into those applications over web services and pulling out information pertinent to the current user. These systems may or may not (likely not) use the same authentication (i.e. Office 365) and are potentially products/services over which we have no (code) control. We are looking to achieve Single Sign-On within this app so that even if the external systems have different authentication the user will (eventually) only need to login once.

I'm trying to work out 1) if this is possible, 2) how to go about doing this. I can see many technical challenges with this but am wondering if it's a solved problem to any extent? At the moment I can only imagine asking for the user's credentials for each external system the first time they log in to the Portal and then storing those credentials for re-use in later requests. We would obviously need to handle when the password changes but I think we would just need to re-show the login form for each service if the credentials failed.

I am however well aware that to achieve this we would need to store the username and password in a retrievable format which is obviously a bad practice and big no-no! We would be looking to implement this portal for relatively large organisations and I can't see this approach getting past any kind of security audit.

So my question is effectively how to securely achieve SSO across applications with different identities? Is it actually possible? I'm happy to hear of products that perhaps solve this problem in anyway.

Many thanks,
James.

Answer (score 0):

the scenario you describe is easily achievable when the web API are protected via Azure AD as well. In that case, you can refer https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIDConnect-DotNet and https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet as examples of asp.net apps where we maintain a server side token cache keyed on the asp.net app user, which allows you to gain access to all the associated web API with a single login. However if you need to access API protected by other providers you will have to refer to their features, practices and SDKs.